# How to make pyramid pattern with numbers?

Tags: java

How to make this pyramid with recursive in java ?

```
     1
    222
   33333
  4444444
     .
     .
     .
```

I made this pattern, but the number of lines increases by 1 instead of 2

```
    static void recursion(int row, int k, int j,int c){
    if(row>c){
        return;
    }
    else{
        if(k==row){
        System.out.println();
        recursion(++row, 0,0,c);
        }
        else if(c-j>row){
        System.out.print(" ");
        ++j;
        recursion(row, k, j,c);
        }
        else{
        System.out.print(row+" ");
        recursion(row, ++k, j,c);
        }   
    }
```

**Result:**

```
     1 
    2 2 
   3 3 3 
  4 4 4 4 
 5 5 5 5 5
```

Comment: From what I can tell, you're only outputting half the pyramid. You have two 2s instead of 3, three 3s instead of 5 and so on. I'm not sure what you mean by the line increases by 1 instead of 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution using your existing design logic, or as I understood it. I changed some variable names so I could remember what did what. (use meaningful names when you code)

```
recursion(1, 0, 0, 7);


static void recursion(int row, int space, int num, int total){
    if (space < total-row){
            System.out.print(' ');
            if (total > 9) System.out.print(' ');
            recursion(row, ++space, num, total);
        }else if(num < row*2-1){
            String r = (row < 10 && total > 9)?" "+row:""+row;
            System.out.print(r);
            recursion(row, space, ++num, total);
        }else{
            System.out.println();
            recursion(++row, 0, 0, total);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: With the online compiler I used, I reach a stack overflow error at 42 rows.  I know this is probably just a homework example, but technically would be a terrible design choice to use recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
static void pyramid(int n, int i) {
    if (i > n) return;
    System.out.println(" ".repeat(n - i) + Integer.toString(i).repeat(i * 2 - 1));
    pyramid(n, i + 1);
}
```

and

```
pyramid(5, 1);
```

result:

```
    1
   222
  33333
 4444444
555555555
```